# no puedo iniciar sesión en formulario Php & Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

No logro iniciar sesión con los datos ingresados
En la base de datos tengo lo siguiente:

[Aquí esta el usuario y la contraseña pero por mas que ingrese esto en el Login.php solo me dice usuario o contraseña incorrectos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHH40.png)

[Esta es la clase usuario y la función de verificar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF8JC.png)

[Aquí esta el SQL de la clase usuario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bvX2.png)

[Aquí esta el Login.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMjHd.png)

[Este es el CONFIG.PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkGUi.png)

lo que quiero corregir es poder iniciar sesión y no caer en el mensaje de error  "Usuario o clave incorrecto" la verdad nose que este haciendo mal

Comment: Por lo que vi en tu base de datos, las contraseñas que tiene cada usuario no están encriptados por `password_hash()`, por eso es que cada vez que intentes iniciar sesión, el `password_verify()` retornará siempre `false`. Cualquier duda, házmela saber :)

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: @Daniel ohhh muchas gracias por la observación, no me di cuenta de eso, al asignar el campo clave en phpmyadmin como password_hash() claro por ejemplo yo  inserto una clave = 123 y queda $2y$10$7CXXVWqPpvM2fcGL8OC.. pero aun así me da error quizas deberia validarlo de otra forma mas simple

Comment: @Kanna De qué forma estás usando el `password_hash()`?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que la clave que esta ingresada en la base de datos no tiene el formato de encriptacion pasword hash.  y adonde se verifica le ingreso hay una funcion `password_verify($clave)`

La solucion es ingresar la clave en la base de datos encriptada en el formato aplicado en la funcion `password_hash($clave)`